# How can I describe these artifacts while training a GAN?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I am studying this paper right now https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.05863.pdf . And here is the code https://github.com/switchablenorms/DeepFashion_Try_On .

I faced a problem while training Clothes Warping Module. I tried about 42(!!!) times to train it tweaking hyperparameters and result is always the same - I get artifacts like in the picture below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtiRl.png)

Why do they appear? It looks as if I do not understand something crucial. Maybe the problem of artifacts in training GANs is covered somewhere.